# Не грузятся последние ответы в дашборде пользователя

Tags: дефект, страница-учётной-записи

У меня почему-то очень долго грузится моя страница, и не прогружаются ответы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя вопросы как видно из картинки прогрузились нормально. Может конечно это затык только у меня, но тем не менее решил написать.

Comment: У меня всё норм. Или уже починили?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Похоже чинят. Сегодня тоже наблюдал баги с ответами в профиле. Правда, во вкладе с ответами, а не просто во вкладе "Активность".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по MSE, должно быть пофикшено.

[No question titles for user's answers in the Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374104/339911)